# CDI on Socket Wildfly or SE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, wildfly, wildfly-8

I need to make a Server socket in a web application that listen for Asterisk AGI requests but i need to enable CDI injection in the socket, don't know how to do that.

Today i already have this socket working very well, the problem is i can't inject a CDI bean with the socket.

Ex:

```
class RequestProcessor implements Runnable
{

private Socket socket;

@Inject
private PhoneService phoneService;

@Override
public void run()
{
  // Do the logic here
}
}
```

Method that receives the request and send to a pool.

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(25000);

Socket client = server.accept();

pool.execute(new RequestProcessor(client));
```

It's not the production code, it's just a illustrated example!

I can't make the @Inject PhoneService phoneService works.

Comment: DI magic doesn't automatically happen when you `new` an object. The object graph must be created by the DI system.

Comment: @MattBall, i know this, thats why i'm asking a way of doing this, because instantiating it myself won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we've already established, `new`ing the `RequestProcessor` won't populate the `@Inject`-annotated field since `new` completely cuts out the DI system. So you need a way to bring it in.

Your goal looks particularly non-trivial because `RequestProcessor` wants a DI-provided dependency (`phoneService`) *and* one that you provide programmatically (`socket`). As a general rule I would advise against mixing the two where possible – once you're using DI, it wants to spread like a virus. Let that happen. If you can design your system so that (almost) everything is injected for you, *that's fanstastic!*

That said, your situation is completely workable.

It looks like you have some method in some class which is a potential injection site. Assuming that this unknown class is in fact created by CDI you could `@Inject` the `PhoneService` into that class, and then pass it to the `RequestProcessor` constructor:

```
public class SomeClass {

  @Inject
  private PhoneService phoneService;

  private void someMethod() {
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(25000);
    Socket client = server.accept();
    pool.execute(new RequestProcessor(client, phoneService));
  }
}
```

Or you could use a factory to create `RequestProcessor` instances, which will basically have the same effect in the end. You can write this factory by hand, which will look pretty familiar:

```
public class RequestProcessorFactory {
  @Inject
  private PhoneService phoneService;

  public RequestProcessor createNewProcessor(Socket socket) {
    return new RequestProcessor(socket, phoneService);
  }
}
```

then inject an instance of that factory into your class:

```
public class SomeClass {

  @Inject
  private RequestProcessorFactory requestProcessorFactory;

  private void someMethod() {
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(25000);
    Socket client = server.accept();
    pool.execute(requestProcessorFactory.createNewProcessor(client));
  }
}
```

There's a third way that you can do it, which is similar to [Guice's assisted injection.](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject) Effectively it just generates that factory implementation for you, if you provide the interface. To my knowledge, CDI does not support this, but there is [at least one CDI extension which does](http://www.warski.org/blog/2010/10/di-and-oo-assisted-inject-in-cdi-weld/).

Happy DI-ing!

Comment: Oh yeah, i mean, the CDI works well, the problem is to Inject a CDI Bean inside a socket.

Comment: Just edited the quest so you can see better the problem.

Comment: Thx for the answer! I'll try the option with factories, by the way, work's if i get the bean programmatically?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by _"by the way, work's if i get the bean programmatically?"_